# How To Snap Align Desktop Icons On Ubuntu MATE

Tags: icons, mate

Essentially what I want is how Windows does it:

```
1) Icons are the same size.
2) There is a snap-to-grid alignment.  A certain number of icons go up and down and left to right on the desktop.
```

I know you can right-click on the desktop and select "Keep Aligned", but it doesn't really work well.  For instance pictures can be taller or wider than other icons.

Comment: If you remove all the thumbnailers, pictures etc should just use the default icons - but then no thumbnails.... (or try editing the thumbnailer setup to produce square thumbnails - look in `/usr/share/thumbnailers`)

Comment: I don't want to necessarily change the icons.  I just want them to snap into place like they would on Windows desktop.

Comment: OK (for that Keep Aligned works though...) Which file manager are you using (they usually manage the desktopy folder stuff)

Comment: Caja.  I am surprised though there are no options in MATE Tweak to set the default desktop icon sizes and alignment.